# Liferay 6.2 on Websphere 8.5; wrong cookies values

Tags: liferay, websphere-8

We are having some problems with some classes we created on one portlet, that creates and retrieves cookies. Our original code works great on local Tomcat, but when we install the portlet on a Websphere 8.5 the value is truncated.
The original content of the cookie is a JSON like this:

> [{"passengerType":"ADULT","passengerAmount":2}]

This is retrieved withour problems in the tomcat but on Websphere:

> String cookieValue = CookieKeys.getCookie(httpRequest, cookieName);

returns this:

> [{"passengerType":"ADULT"

Looks like the problem is with the comma, but I've checked the Websphere documentation and googled a bit around and haven't found any reference.
Have somebody run on something similar?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like a bug. You will need to create PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: I will do it then.
Thanks for your comment @Gas.